# How to add advertisements to flash app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ads

I've been working on an iphone app with flash For a while... Now that the app is ready I would like to add advertisements to it (the app Will be free, so i'll gain something) but i don't Know How to do it... Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Mochi Media](http://www.mochimedia.com/). They have an API for embedding ads. I have used them in the past for adding advertisments to games I have developed and had good results.